# Control.Layer collapse option for overlay layers with leaflet directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, leaflet

Does anyone knows how to set the collapsed control.layers options for a group of base and overlay Layers added with leaflet directive? 
In my scenario, the control.layer should be always expanded.

I tried to add an options object on my leaflet directive configuration, like:

```
angular.extend($scope, {
    center: {
        lat: 0,
        lng: 0,
        zoom: 1,
        autoDiscover: true
    },
    geofences: {},
    defaults: {
        scrollWheelZoom: true,
        zoomControl: false
    },
    layers: {
        options: {
            collapsed: false
        },
        baselayers: {
            defaultOSMMap: {
                name: 'Map at Day',
                type: 'xyz',
                url: 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
            },
            osmNight: {
                name: 'Map at Night ',
                type: 'xyz',
                url: 'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/{key}/{styleId}/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                layerParams: {
                    key: 'BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707',
                    styleId: 999
                }
            },
            googleHybrid: {
                name: 'Google Hybrid',
                layerType: 'HYBRID',
                type: 'google'
            },
            googleRoadmap: {
                name: 'Google Streets',
                layerType: 'ROADMAP',
                type: 'google'
            }
        },
        overlays: {
            communityAreas: {
                name: 'Community Areas',
                type: 'group',
                visible: false
            }
        }
    },
    controls: {
    }
```

and then, on the angular-leaflet directive file, adding the following:

```
 // We have baselayers to add to the map
 _leafletLayers.resolve(leafletLayers);
 leafletData.setLayers(leafletLayers, attrs.id);

 leafletLayers.baselayers = {};
 leafletLayers.controls = {};
 leafletLayers.controls.layers = new L.control.layers({}, {}, isDefined(layers.options) ? layers.options : {}); --> this is the line I modified
 leafletLayers.controls.layers.setPosition(defaults.controlLayersPosition);
 leafletLayers.controls.layers.addTo(map);
```

but I got errors related to the layers on the debug console, like: "Uncaught Error: No value provided for variable {s} " at leaflet.js file.

Maybe is the way I'm instantiating the base and overlay layers on the angular-leaflet-directive... Any thoughts?

Comment: One way I found to achieve the scenario was by getting a reference to the current control.layer, expand it and then removing the mouseout and mouseover events:
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    leafletData.getLayers().then(function(layers){
            layers.controls.layers._expand();
            L.DomEvent.off(layers.controls.layers._container, 'mouseout', layers.controls.layers._collapse);
            L.DomEvent.off(layers.controls.layers._container, 'mouseover', layers.controls.layers._expand);
        });

but Is there any way to do it by passing the options object to the leaflet directive?

Comment: "I couldn't make it work" is not very helpful. When asking a question on Stack Overflow, please do your best to explain what you expected to happen, and what did happen.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. What I want is to have the layer control always expanded. I tried with the changes I mentioned but I got errors related to the layers on the debug console, like: "Uncaught Error: No value provided for variable {s} " at leaflet.js.

Then I tried with the code I putted on my previous comment and it worked. Sorry for not clarifying the question (it is the first time I asked something in here :))

Comment: You should edit those things into your question instead of leaving them in comments - they're important and people don't always read the comments.

Comment: Done! At first that was the first thing that came to my mind, but I couldn´t find the "edit" button :) Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a bit late now, but just in case anyone else is having the same issue (as i just had !)

This is how I set the control layer to be expanded expanded.

Keith

```
angular.extend($scope, {
    center: {
        lat: 0,
        lng: 0,
        zoom: 1,
        autoDiscover: true
    },
    geofences: {},
    defaults: {
        scrollWheelZoom: true,
        zoomControl: false,
        controls :{
                    layers : {
                        visible: true,
                        position: 'topright',
                        collapsed: false
                             }
                    }
    },
    layers: ...
```